# $\mathbb{Z}/(n+1)\mathbb{Z}\mapsto[n]=\{0,1,...n\}$

Tags: category-theory

Does this mapping between objects
$$ 
\mathbb{Z}/(n+1)\mathbb{Z}\mapsto[n]=\{0,1,...n\}
$$
for all n > or = to 0

mapping between morhisms
$$
(\mathbb Z/(n+1)\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/(m+1)\mathbb Z)\mapsto([n]=\{0,1,...n\}\to[m]=\{0,1,...m\})
$$

induces a forgetful functor, forgetting the congruence relation, between a subcategory of the category of rings (the one in which objects are of the above form) to the simplex category ?

Comment: What ring are you referring to when you say $\mathbb{Z}/n + 1\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I suppose you mean $\mathbb Z/(n+1)\mathbb Z$? The lack of brackets is very confusing.

Comment: Another question: What categories is the functor between?

Comment: What do all the other rings map to?

Comment: This question carries an *extremely* strong impression of being an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You should post a new question asking about *what goal you are trying to achieve*, rather than ask questions solely about an idea you had to do so.

Comment: But you did not specify a map, not on objects and not on morphisms

Comment: Isn't the map I have written a map between an object of a subcategory of the category of rings (where the objects are quotient ring of the above form) and an object of the simplex category ?
Morphisms from the simplex category are the usual ones

Answer (score 1):

No, for two reasons:

- There are rings that aren't isomorphic to a ring of the form $\mathbb{Z}/(n+1)\mathbb{Z}$, and you haven't specified how the alleged functor should act on those
- You haven't specified what to do on morphisms. There is no *explicit* indication, and I don't see what you've written as implicitly suggesting any such action.

Comment: I am looking at a subcategory of the category of rings where the objects are of the form $\mathbb{Z}/(n+1)\mathbb{Z}$ so that the functor act only on these ones
Namely the image of this object by the functor should coincide with the n-simplex set